# Restricted set operations on python dictionary key views

Tags: python, set

Lets see the code snippet below:

```
d = {1:1}
keys = d.keys()

print(keys & {1,2,3})# {1}
d[2] = 2
print(keys & {1,2,3}) # {1,2} # keys() is a view/reference
print({1,2}.issubset({1,2,3})) # True
print(keys.issubset({1,2,3})) # 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'issubset'
```

It is mentioned in the official documents on [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable.
>   ..  Then these set operations are available (“other” refers either to
>   another view or a set): [&,|, ^, ^]

If the keys are set-like, why are the set operation on them restricted to those four infix operations. Why, for example, side-effect free operation like `issuperset` or `issubset` not permitted?

Comment: they are `Keys views`  = `set-like` not a `set` itself. If you want to perform sets operations, transform your keys view into a set.

Comment: @levi on what basic are some, and not other, of the set-operations selected?

Comment: `issubsert` isn't `issubset`.

Comment: corrected the typo.

Answer (score 6):

> Why, for example, are not side-effect free operation like `issuperset` or `issubset` operation not permitted?

They are; you just have to use the `>=` and `<=` operators:

```
print(keys <= {1, 2, 3})
```

They also support `isdisjoint` in method form, since there's no operator for it:

```
print(keys.isdisjoint({1, 2, 3}))
```

Comment: Is there any reason why superset/subset testing operations are not available in method form?

Comment: @DurgaDatta: I dunno. The [dict view PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/) proposed implementing the method forms, but at some point, they decided not to. There's probably a conversation about it buried somewhere like the Python-Dev mailing list or the issue tracker.